# use .html() method to set javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I'm trying to create a "mini html editor" using a `textarea` that sets the html in an `iframe`using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#outputtxt').keyup(function(){
            var tval = $('#outputtxt').val();
            $("#frameid").contents().find("body").html(tval);
        });
    });
```

Works fine for simple html and styling. Doesn't seem to be working for class or id css and doesn't seem to be working for scripts. can the `.html()` method be used for that?

Comment: This is an ideal question for a JSFiddle or the new `Code snippet` tool in the Stack Overflow editor. That will help clarify what the problem is.

Comment: OK. Here's my JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6uzsep5d/). The weird thing is- classes and ids seem to work in JSFiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of iframe, then css will work.

Comment: When I started, I used a div. font color and such worked but class or id css didn't.